# Django: Trying to click on a link and remove an assigned client

Tags: python, django

Good morning. I am having an issue trying to remove a client from an assigned bed. I created a one-item form called "RoomUpdate" that will allow a user to add a client to a bed that is empty via a dropdown through a ModelChoiceField.

When the bed is full, it does not allow the access to the drop down, instead, I have a link that states "remove client." What I want to happen is when I click that button, it assigns the default value of None to that bed in that room.

What's tricky, at least to my new-ish to Django mind, is how I do this through multiple tables. Having looked for multiple answers and tried different things, I know I've lost track of what I'm doing so I definitely could use some help.

models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    room_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    room_number = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    shelter_id = models.ForeignKey(Shelter)
    max_occupancy = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    floor_location = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.room_number


class Bed(models.Model):
    bed_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    room_id = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='beds')
    bed_size = models.ForeignKey(BedSize)
    client_assigned = models.ForeignKey(Clients, null=True, blank=True,     default=None)
```

forms.py

```
class RoomUpdate(forms.ModelForm):
    client_assigned = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Clients.objects.all(), required=False)

#def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #super(RoomUpdate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #self.fields['client_assigned'].choices.insert(0, ('','---------' ) )

class Meta:
     model = Room
     fields = ( 'client_assigned', )
```

views.py

```
def room_update(request, pk, template_name='shelter/room_edit.html'):
    rooms = get_object_or_404(Room, pk=pk)
    form = RoomUpdate(request.POST or None, instance=rooms)
    beds = Bed.objects.filter(room_id=pk)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
            return redirect('/shelter/')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'rooms': rooms, 'beds':beds,})


def remove_client(request, pk):
    rooms = get_object_or_404(Room, pk=pk)
    bed = Bed.objects.filter(room_id=pk)
    form = RoomUpdate(request.POST)
    template_fail = 'clients/invalid_permissions.html'
    if request.method=='POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            bed.objects.update(client_assigned=None)
            bed.save()
    else:
        return redirect(request, template_fail)
    return render_to_response(request, {'rooms': rooms, 'bed': bed})
```

template

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="room box-shadow">
        <h4>Room {{ rooms.room_number }}</h4>
        <table>
            {% for i in rooms.beds.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>Bed ID: </td>
                <td>{{i.bed_id }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bed Size: </td>
                <td>{{i.bed_size }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">Client: </td>
                <td>
                    {% if i.client_assigned %} 
                        {{ i.client_assigned }} 
                        <br \>
                        <a href="{% url 'shelter:removeclient' i.bed_id %}">Remove Client</a> 
                    {% else %} 
                       {{ form.client_assigned }} 
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <hr class="style-two" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with this a bit and making some sort of progress. If I change the url from the same as the edit, I get it to work in that it deletes from the table and redirects the user to a new page.

I would prefer it not redirect the user to a new page, but rather, update the page that's there.

Thoughts?

The new view looks like this:

```
def remove_client(request, pk, template_name='shelter/test.html'):
    bed = Bed.objects.filter(bed_id=pk).update(client_assigned=None)
    return render(request, template_name, { 'bed':bed })
```

Answer (score 0):

Further diving into this, I found a solution I rather like and actually works in a way I wanted but couldn't figure out. Instead of focusing on the room, I realized that I needed to focus on the smaller container -- the bed -- and since it can move around, it would be the better choice.

Currently, this functionality allows me to move beds to different rooms, remove clients by selecting the '----' selector, and allows me to add clients.

So here is the answer I came up with:

forms.py

```
class RoomUpdate(forms.ModelForm):
    bed_id = forms.CharField()
    room_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Room.objects.all())
    bed_size = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=BedSize.objects.all(), required=False)
    client_assigned = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Clients.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
         model = Bed
         fields = ('bed_id', 'client_assigned', 'room_id', 'bed_size' )
```

views.py

```
def room_update(request, pk, template_name='shelter/room_edit.html'):
    beds = get_object_or_404(Bed,pk=pk)
    form = RoomUpdate(request.POST or None, instance=beds)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/shelter/')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'beds':beds,})
```

room_edit.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
 <div class="room box-shadow">
    <h4>Room </h4>

    <table>

    <tr>
        <td>Room: </td>
        <td>{{ form.room_id }}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Bed ID: </td>
        <td>{{ form.bed_id }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bed Size: </td>
        <td>{{ form.bed_size }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Client: </td>
        <td>{{ form.client_assigned }}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr class="style-two" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</div>


</form>
```